# Play framework 2 and automatically adding an add_date to an ebeans item

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a small difficulty with ebeans.

I used to create items with the following code, populating the addDate:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericModel extends Model {

    @Id
    protected Long id;

    @UpdatedTimestamp
    @Version
    private Date lastUpdate;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    protected Date addDate;

    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate(){
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public Date getAddDate(){
        return addDate;
    }

}
```

However, as I need to synchronise the data with an offline device, I changed it to:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericModel extends Model {

    @Id
    protected Long id;

    @UpdatedTimestamp
    @Version
    private Date lastUpdate;

    protected Date addDate;

    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate(){
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public Date getAddDate(){
        return addDate;
    }

    @WhenCreated
    private void addCreateTimestamp(){
        if(this.addDate == null) this.addDate = new Date();
    }

}
```

But this doesn't work, as there is an exception that the addDate cannot be null when inserting.

Is there another way of populating the addDate is not set (for the synchronisation I sometimes I need to set the addDate manually so it is the same as the master).

[EDIT:] this problem doesn't seem to show up on my development system with men db, but when deployed with MySql

Answer (score 0):

`@WhenCreated` is just an alias for `@CreatedTimestamp`. What are you expecting putting this annotation before the `addCreateTimestamp()` method. This method is never executed in your case, so the `addDate` is never set.

Try this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericModel extends Model {
    // ...
    protected Date addDate;
    // ...

    @Override
    public void save() {
        addCreateTimestamp();
        super.save();
    }

    private void addCreateTimestamp(){
        if(this.addDate == null) this.addDate = new Date();
    }

    // ...
```